# Find unknown parameters from NonLinear fitted data

Tags: equation-solving, fitting, nonlinear

I obtained the fitted model from the image using the following code:

```
kguess = 3;
nguess = 1;
data = {{0.010000000000000004`, 0.`}, {0.029999999999999995`, 
    0.1835304721030043`}, {0.10000000000000002`, 
    0.49498712446351933`}, {0.3`, 
    0.8998025751072961`}, {10.000000000000002`, 
    0.9641931330472102`}, {100.00000000000004`, 
    1.0063948497854078`}, {10.000000000000002`, 
    1.0244935622317597`}, {30.000000000000004`, 
    1.0407467811158797`}, {10.000000000000002`, 
    1.0478068669527896`}, {999.9999999999998`, 
    1.0515150214592275`}, {30.000000000000004`, 
    1.0598712446351932`}, {30.000000000000004`, 
    1.0602017167381972`}, {299.99999999999994`, 
    1.067`}, {999.9999999999998`, 1.069420600858369`}, {1.`, 
    1.0807639484978542`}, {100.00000000000004`, 
    1.0938369098712446`}, {3.0000000000000004`, 
    1.1059270386266093`}, {299.99999999999994`, 
    1.107145922746781`}, {2999.9999999999977`, 
    1.1216223175965667`}, {10000.00000000001`, 
    1.1313605150214594`}, {100.00000000000004`, 
    1.1466051502145922`}, {299.99999999999994`, 
    1.1504721030042917`}, {999.9999999999998`, 1.171429184549356`}};

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, (1 - Exp[-k*((t)^n)])*dhnematicmax, {{k, kguess}, {n, nguess}}, t]
```

[image: model]

If I know that the variable `k`(which is equal to 3.90743 in this example) from the fitted model is equal to `k = kref*Exp[(-E/8.314)*((1/360.15) - (1/353.15))];`. How can I find the unknown variables `kref` and `E`in Mathematica using `NonlinearModelFit` or any other function?

Comment: You can estimate `k` but not `kref` and `E`.  (Note that `E` is a reserved word and you should avoid uppercase letters for variables in *Mathematica*.  Also `dhnematicmax` is not defined but I suspect has a value of 1.2.)  Suppose `k = a + b`.  Just knowing `k` there is an infinite set of values of `a` and `b` that satisfy `k = a + b`.

Comment: @JimB I was thinking that perhaps it could be use something like: nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data,(1 - Exp[-kref*Exp[(-e/8.314)*((1/360.15) - (1/353.15))]*((t)^n)])*1.2, {{kref, krefguess}, {e, eguess}}, t]. In other words, simply replacing `k` by `kref*Exp[(-E/8.314)*((1/360.15) - (1/353.15))]`.(I now change "E" as "e")

Comment: What happened when you did that?

Comment: @JimB It works for this data but for some other it does not. It shows overflow for some other data. I am not sure how to overcome overflow. I think it overflows because E (or e) gets very big in the guessing. What would be the correct sintaxis to limit E (or e) to be less than something in `NonlinearModelFit`?. I tried `nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data,(1 - Exp[-kref*Exp[(-e/8.314)*((1/360.15) - (1/353.15))]*((t)^n)])*1.2, {{kref, krefguess}, {e, eguess,0<e<1000}}, t]` but it did not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get there from here.  You can estimate `k` (which equals `kref Exp[(-e/8.314) ((1/360.15) - (1/353.15))]` but there is an infinite set of `kref`:`e` pairs that give you the exact same prediction equation.

Consider the results from

```
dhnematicmax = 1.2
k = kref Exp[(-e/8.314) ((1/360.15) - (1/353.15))]
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, (1 - Exp[-k*((t)^n)])*dhnematicmax, {{kref, 4}, {e, 1}, {n, nguess}}, t]
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {kref -> 5.06019, e -> -39053., n -> 0.893056} *)
```

That "works" in the sense that values are given for `kref` and `e`.  However, look at the estimated correlation matrix of the parameter estimators:

```
nlm["CorrelationMatrix"] // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1. & 1. & 0.907781 \\
 1. & 1. & 0.907781 \\
 0.907781 & 0.907781 & 1. \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

This says that the first two parameters (`kref` and `e`) are perfectly correlated:  If you know one value you know the other.

The structure of you model should be what convinces you about the inability to obtain meaningful estimates of `kref` and `e`.  But look at the mean of the squares of the residuals:

```
Mean[nlm["FitResiduals"]^2]
(* 0.0143249 *)
```

Now suppose I arbitrarily declare that `kref` is not 5.06019 but 10 (twice the initial result) and fit the model with that parameter fixed at my made-up value for `kref`:

```
kref = 10;
k = kref Exp[(-e/8.314) ((1/360.15) - (1/353.15))]
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, (1 - Exp[-k*((t)^n)])*dhnematicmax, {{e, 1}, {n, nguess}}, t]
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {e -> -141954., n -> 0.893056} *)
Mean[nlm["FitResiduals"]^2]
(* 0.0143249 *)
```

We see the same exact values for `n` and the mean of the squared fit residuals but now `e` is estimated to be a wildly different number.

If we calculate the values for `k` from each model we see the same resulting value:

```
kref Exp[(-e/8.314) ((1/360.15) - (1/353.15))] /. kref -> 5.060185197547436` /. e -> -39052.97750976022`
(* 3.90743 *)

kref Exp[(-e/8.314) ((1/360.15) - (1/353.15))] /. kref -> 10 /. e -> -141953.5476546686`
(* 3.90743 *)
```

Comment: This is a great answer @JimB thank you !!!